# Totally automatic Bluetooth connection to Windows 7 Laptop

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I have seen similar questions but nothing exactly describing my problem.

I have a dell Inspiron laptop running Windows 7. Recently, I bought a set of IWANTIT ISBT10013 wireless Bluetooth speakers.

I have managed to connect them up via Bluetooth and when connected they work fine.

The problem is that when I switch them off, or am turning the computer on for the first time, and then switch them on, my laptop will not connect to them automatically.  I have to carry out the following actions (which are becoming more and more of a chore):

- after turning on the speakers..
- open up devices and printers
- right click on the ISBT10013 icon
- choose Bluetooth operations
- wait for it to search for services
- then when it sorts itself out, choose the only option - 'listen to music'
- it will then establish a Bluetooth connection to the speakers
- close down all the Windows that have been opened and go listen to some music etc.

I have tried setting my system such that the the speakers are my default audio playback device, and this works fine, but only after I carry out all the above steps to make that Bluetooth connection.

The problem is further exasperated by the fact that if not being used for 20 mins, the speakers go on standby breaking the Bluetooth connection and requiring all the above to be done again.

As a bit of a workaround I have placed a copy of the speaker Bluetooth short cut into startup.. but as implied, it only helps the little it does, at start up.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have your Bluetooth services to start automatically?

Comment: Hi,  Thank you for your question.  My Bluetooth is enabled automatically from startup.